# Why does failing to recognise equality mess up C# List<T> sort?

Tags: c#, list

This is a somewhat obscure question, but after wasting an hour tracking down the bug, I though it worth asking...

I wrote a custom ordering for a `struct`, and made one mistake:

- My struct has a special state, let us call this "min".
- If the struct is in the min state, then it's smaller than any other struct.
- My `CompareTo` method made one mistake: `a.CompareTo(b)` would return `-1` whenever `a` was "min", but of course if `b` is also "min" it should return 0.

Now, this mistake completely messed up a `List<MyStruct>` `Sort()` method: the whole list would (sometimes) come out in a random order.

- My list contained exactly one object in "min" state.
- It seems my mistake could only affect things if the one "min" object was compared to itself.
- Why would this even happen when sorting?
- And even if it did, how can it cause the relative order of two "non-min" objects to be wrong?

Using the LINQ `OrderBy` method can cause an infinite loop...

Small, complete, test example:

```cs
struct MyStruct : IComparable<MyStruct>
{
    public int State;
    public MyStruct(int s) { State = s; }
    public int CompareTo(MyStruct rhs)
    {
        // 10 is the "min" state.  Otherwise order as usual
        if (State == 10) { return -1; } // Incorrect
        /*if (State == 10) // Correct version
        {
            if (rhs.State == 10) { return 0; }
            return -1;
        }*/
        if (rhs.State == 10) { return 1; }
        return this.State - rhs.State;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("MyStruct({0})", State);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static int Main()
    {
        var list = new List<MyStruct>();
        var rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        {
            int x = rnd.Next(15);
            if (x >= 10) { ++x;  }
            list.Add(new MyStruct(x));
        }
        list.Add(new MyStruct(10));
        list.Sort();
        // Never returns...
        //list = list.OrderBy(item => item).ToList();

        Console.WriteLine("list:");
        foreach (var x in list) { Console.WriteLine(x); }

        for (int i = 1; i < list.Count(); ++i)
        {
            Console.Write("{0} ", list[i].CompareTo(list[i - 1]));
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Without looking into the implementation, consider some routine that iterates through a set of items, looking for one that is smaller or equal to a particular known member of that set. The code doesn't have to do anything special when it gets to the end without finding one because it "knows" that it will always, at the least, encounter the actual member. Until it meets your broken equality function.

Comment: Oh, and using a magic number in the middle of a valid range of numbers, that makes me itch.

Comment: This is an implementation detail. Many sort routines are built around handling the knowledge of transitive comparison results, meaning that if a < b and b < c, then a < c, but break down completely if this isn't true. It does in fact compare 10 to 10 so it may very well confuse itself.

Comment: @MrLister Neither of the two things you bring up are the reasons here, the problem is the comparison method that produces incorrect results.

Comment: Works for me with correct sorting & the linq version always returning. (VS2012, .net 4.5). Why does the CompareTo method need to be more complex than return this.State - rhs.State; If State is limited to < 9 normally & 10 for the special state, then surely this would work.

Comment: Take that back - adding 10 twice makes it fail & linq not return. PLus I spotted State is not limited to <9;

Comment: Looking at the sequence linq does - it appears to constantly repeat the sort until nothing is changed - with your code as it will always treat two values of 10 as being different with the first smaller, so constantly swap them - hence the infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting thoughts.  @PaulF: the example is just an artificial example; my "real" struct was a lot more complicated; too complicated for an example here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It seems my mistake could only affect things if the one "min" object was compared to itself.

Not quite. It could **also** be caused if there were two different "min" objects. In the case of the list sorted this particular time, it can only happen if the item is compared to itself. But the other case is worth considering generally in terms of why supplying a non-transitive comparer to a method that expects a transitive comparer is a very bad thing.

> Why would this even happen when sorting?

Why not?

`List<T>.Sort()` works by using the `Array.Sort<T>` on its items. `Array.Sort<T>` in turn uses a mixture of Insertion Sort, Heapsort and Quicksort, but to simplify let's consider a general quicksort. For simplicity we'll use `IComparable<T>` directly, rather than via `System.Collections.Generic.Comparer<T>.Default`:

```
public static void Quicksort<T>(IList<T> list) where T : IComparable<T>
{
  Quicksort<T>(list, 0, list.Count - 1);
}
public static void Quicksort<T>(IList<T> list, int left, int right) where T : IComparable<T>
{
  int i = left;
  int j = right;
  T pivot = list[(left + right) / 2];

  while(i <= j)
  {
    while(list[i].CompareTo(pivot) < 0)
      i++;

    while(list[j].CompareTo(pivot) > 0)
      j--;

    if(i <= j)
    {
      T tmp = list[i];
      list[i] = list[j];
      list[j] = tmp;
      i++;
      j--;
    }
  }

  if(left < j)
    Quicksort(list, left, j);

  if(i < right)
    Quicksort(list, i, right);
}
```

This works as follows:

1. Pick an element, called a pivot, from the list(we use the middle).
2. Reorder the list so that all elements with values less than the pivot come before the pivot, while all elements with values greater than the pivot come after it.
3. The pivot is now in its final position, with an unsorted sub-list before and after it. Recursively apply the same steps to these two sub-lists.

Now, there are two things to note about the example code above.

The first is that we do not prevent `pivot` being compared with itself. We could do this, but why would we? For one thing, we need some sort of comparison code to do this, which is precisely what you've already provided in your `CompareTo()` method. In order to avoid the wasted `CompareTo` we'd have to either call `CompareTo()`* an extra time for each comparison (!) or else track the position of `pivot` which would add more waste than it removed.

> And even if it did, how can it cause the relative order of two "non-min" objects to be wrong?

Because quicksort partitions, it doesn't do one massive sort, but a series of mini-sorts. Therefore an incorrect comparison gets a series of opportunities to mess up parts of those sorts, each time leading to a sub-list of incorrectly sorted values that the algorithm considers "dealt with". So in those cases where the bug in the comparer hits, its damage can be spread throughout much of the list. Just as it does its sort by a series of mini-sorts, so it will do a buggy sort by a series of buggy mini-sorts.

> Using the LINQ OrderBy method can cause an infinite loop

It uses a variant of Quicksort that guarantees stability; two equivalent item will still have the same relative order after the search as before. The extra complexity is presumably leading to it not only comparing the item to itself, but then continuing to do so forever, as it tries to make sure that it is both in front of itself, but also in the same order to itself as it was before. (Yes, that last sentence makes no sense, and that's exactly why it never returns).

*If this was a reference rather than value type then we could do `ReferenceEquals` quickly, but aside from the fact that this won't be any good with structs, and the fact that if that really was a time-saver for the type in question it should have `if(ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return 0;` in the `CompareTo` anyway, it still wouldn't fix the bug once there was more than one "min" items in the list.